# what is happening in java list and its nodes ?

Tags: java

guys i'm a confused the how newLink and currentLink are changing the list , i'm thinking that when we call the method then they're created and the method does not return a Node object so why the list is changed when we change currentLink and newLink and what is happening exactly ?

// DOUBLY LINKED LIST ADDITION
    // Insert after the provided key

```
public boolean insertAfterKey(String homeOwnerName, int houseNumber, int key){

    Neighbor theNewLink = new Neighbor(homeOwnerName, houseNumber);

    Neighbor currentNeighbor = firstLink; // Starts search at first link

    // while the current houseNumber isn't the key keep looking

    while(currentNeighbor.houseNumber != key){

        currentNeighbor = currentNeighbor.next; // Switch to the next Neighbor

        // If we get to the last Neighbor without a match leave the method

        if(currentNeighbor == null){

            return false;

        }

    }

    // If we make it here we have a match for the key

    // If the match was for the last Neighbor in the list

    if(currentNeighbor == lastLink){

        // Assign the new Neighbor as the last link

        theNewLink.next = null;
        lastLink = theNewLink;

    } else {

        // It didn't match for the last link
        // So take next from the Neighbor that was 
        // here previously and assign theNewLink to
        // the previous Neighbor

        theNewLink.next = currentNeighbor.next;
        currentNeighbor.next.previous = theNewLink;

    }

    theNewLink.previous = currentNeighbor;
    currentNeighbor.next = theNewLink;
    return true;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignments to `theNewLink` and `currentNeighbor` can't change the list, since these are assignments to local variables.

The statements that actually change the list are :

```
currentNeighbor.next.previous = theNewLink; // this makes the link before which the new
                                            // link is added to point to the new link
```

and

```
currentNeighbor.next = theNewLink; // this makes the link after which the new link is
                                   // added to point to the new link
```

since they make existing links of the list point to the newly created link.